# how can i let my friends visit my webserver?

Tags: apache, localhost, xampp

How do I make it so that my friends can visit my localhost website by typing in my IP address into their browser address bar?

I'm using XAMPP what steps do i need to take etc.

Answer (score 1):

[StackOverflow addressed in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet)